# How can I include jQuery on every page of my site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello I'm new to programming sorry for the super noob question, I started using JQuery a while ago just some simple plugins for a menu to stay on top and make a clickable div and it's working fine, this div and this menu are present on every page of my web site, they are currently working in my default.aspx page, my question is, am I supposed to copy paste this:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/page_theme/javascript/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="/page_theme/javascript/jquery.clickable.div.js"></script>
```

These are needed on every single page of my site to make it work, for example in the other sections like faq.aspx, my_account.aspx, contact_us.aspx...etc. The problem is that this website has more than 50 pages and I would like these 2 plugins to work on everyone of them since this is the main menu and this div also appears on every one of them.

Sorry for the noobish question just trying to learn how to do this....thx

Comment: Are you using a Master Page?

Comment: use a common header file for all pages

Comment: No I'm not using a master page, it's technically not my web site I just manage it, so I guess I will have to copy paste that on every file, there are nearly a hundred, that's what I was trying to avoid...

Comment: How do the menu and the div appear on every page? Were those copied and pasted on all 100 pages?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Javascript files need to be included on every page you would like the functionality to work.

To ease the pain of this you could perhaps put the scripts in a separate file which you include on each page when required. This has the added advantage that you can then update the `scripts.aspx` file once if you add a new script and each page that includes the file is updated.

To do this, set up a separate `scripts.aspx` file containing your scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/page_theme/javascript/menu.js"></script>
<script src="/page_theme/javascript/jquery.clickable.div.js"></script>
```

On each page you want the scripts to appear you could then write:

`<% Response.WriteFile("scripts.aspx") %>`

This is of course if `scripts.aspx` is in the same directory. Update the file path if need be.

Comment: Thx for the answer I think I'll do it this, seems like the best option for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a common page such as `common.aspx` or `config.aspx` and including this at the top of each page. Considering your nav bar that will be on every page uses jQuery, it might be a good idea so that you do not forget.

Another option is to create a specific page such as `header.aspx` that includes the code for your navbar/menu as well as your jQuery links, and including it at the top of every page instead of copy pasting the code.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you'll have to add those to each page.

You could create a new page, say "headers.inc", and reference it inside the Head of each page:

```
<head>    
<!-- #include file = "headers.inc" -->
</head>
```

And since you're using .NET, you may find Master Pages to your liking (I don't).  That would also allow you to consolidate your JS includes.

Also, if you decide to include by storing your scripts in a .NET variable, you can use this shorthand (instead of Response.Write):

```
<head>
<%=scripts%>
</head>
```